# Need object values on JSP in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

In one method of controller class, I have below code 
*map.put("contact1", new Contact());

map.put("contactList1", contactService.listContact());*
And in my resulting jsp, I am getting "contact1" and "contactList1" with its values. I understand from this that keys of the map are available in resulting jsp. 
 I have a login jsp where I provide username and password in text boxes and then request goes to a method in controller and from there I go to 2nd jsp. I need values of username and password there on 2nd jsp. SO should I put username and password in map in controller method or is there any other way if getting values on 2nd jsp. Please help me with some code share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be carrying over a password value from request to request. It's a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Depending on how you get the values from the first jsp, request parameters, serialized in JSON, etc., you can retrieve them in your `@Controller` handler method

For example

```
public String handleThem(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    model.addAttribute("password", password);
    return "view-name";
}
```

You can then simply use EL to retrieve them in your jsp.

```
${username}
${password}
```